# Rust function that allocates memory and calls a C++ callback crashes

Tags: c++, rust, ffi

Rust code:

```rust
#[repr(C)]
pub struct Tmp {
    pub callback: extern "C" fn(i: i32),
}

#[no_mangle]
pub extern "C" fn set_callback(callback: extern "C" fn(i: i32)) -> *mut Tmp {
    let mut tmp = Box::new(Tmp { callback });
    println!("tmp as ptr: {:p}", tmp); // >> here <<
    &mut *tmp
}

#[no_mangle]
pub extern "C" fn use_callback(tmp_ptr: *mut Tmp) {
    unsafe {
        ((*tmp_ptr).callback)(1);
        ((*tmp_ptr).callback)(3);
    }
}
```

C++ code:

```cpp
struct Tmp {
    void (*callback)(int32_t);
};

typedef Tmp*(__stdcall* set_callback_t)(void(*callback_t)(int32_t));
typedef void(__stdcall* use_callback_t)(Tmp*);

void callback(int32_t i) {
    printf("%d\n", i * 2);
}

int main() {
    // ... loading rust part as .dll
    // ... checking if loaded correctly
    Tmp* tmp_ptr = set_callback(callback);
    printf("tmp_ptr %p\n", tmp_ptr);
    use_callback(tmp_ptr);
    // ... freeing the .dll
}
```

When I compile this the program, it works as expected. The printed values of pointer to `Tmp` structure in Rust and C++ match. When I comment out the `println` in Rust, the C++ program crashes, which means that there is something wrong with this (probably Rust part) code.

I am using the Rust code as a .dll. I would like to pass a pointer to C++ function to the `set_callback` function, and then I would like to use that pointer in the `use_callback` function when I call `use_callback` in the C++ code.

For what I understand, at the end I will have to call a Rust function to drop the `Tmp` structure, but I left that out.

Comment: I'm a little concerned that there may be a problem with your use of `__stdcall`.  `extern fn`s in Rust use the C calling convention by default, not stdcall.  You should probably use `__cdecl` instead.  You could also use `extern "stdcall" fn` on the Rust side, but that's only valid on 32-bit Windows.

Comment: Your C++ callback function also needs to be marked with `extern "C"`

Answer (score 5):

`Box` in Rust is similar to `std::unique_ptr` in C++. The way you construct `tmp`, the data pointed to will be freed at the end of the function.

In order to "leak" the pointer into C++ world, you should use [`Box::into_raw`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/boxed/struct.Box.html#method.into_raw).

Note that as there is no guarantee that Rust and C++ allocate memory the same way; you will have to pass the pointer back to Rust and use [`Box::from_raw`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/boxed/struct.Box.html#method.from_raw) to deallocate it.

Comment: Returning `Box::into_raw(tmp)` instead of `&mut *tmp` seems to work. Thank you.