# FFI callback and segfault

Tags: rust, ffi

I’m learning Rust and experimenting with FFI callbacks. I wrote a library that does the following:

- Initializes a C data structure.
- Initializes a wrapper Rust struct for this data structure. The constructor expects a function pointer, the callback `test_cb`.

The usage looks like this:

```
let test_cb = move |n: i32| n * 2;
let mut _test_worker = new(test_cb);
```

This stores a pointer to the Rust data structure on the C side and vice versa: there’s a pointer to the C structure in Rust:

```
pub struct Worker {
    ptr: WorkerPtr,        // Pointer to the C data structure
    cb: fn(i32) -> i32,    // Callback function
}

struct WorkerPtr(NonNull<worker>);
unsafe impl marker::Send for WorkerPtr {}
```

```c
struct worker_s {
    void* rust_object;  // Pointer to the Rust data structure
};
```

C calls Rust indicating the Rust struct pointer, Rust dereferences the pointer and calls a method on it: `Worker.trigger_callback`, the result is sent back to the C world:

```
#[no_mangle]
pub extern "C" fn rust_callback(w: *mut Worker, raw_n: c_int) -> c_int {
    let n = raw_n as i32;
    println!("rust_callback: {}", n);
    unsafe {
        let out = (*w).trigger_callback(n);
        out as c_int
    }
}
```

Everything works fine, the method in the Rust object is successfully called, as expected, the program output looks like this (following the implementation shown above):

```
worker_new: worker = 0x7f9834d000c0
worker_set_rust_object: worker = 0x7f9834d000c0 rust_object = 0x10ca21000
trigger_callback: worker = 0x7f9834d000c0 rust_object = 0x10ca21000
rust_callback: 100
trigger_callback: 100
got: 200
```

In my real use case, I’m using the bytes library and my callback is a `fn(bytes::Bytes) -> bytes::Bytes`. My tests work fine and `Worker::trigger_callback` is successfully called, but under certain scenarios I’m getting a segmentation fault and EXC_BAD_ACCESS when calling the function pointer that’s stored in the structure (`self.cb/Worker.cb`). On the Rust side I’m using a single thread. I can also confirm that the bytes object is correct, I can even print its length using `bytes.len()`, the only issue is the `self.cb/Worker.cb` call.

I’ve been trying to debug and find the cause with no luck, so I’m looking for feedback on this approach, etc. The full code is available [here](https://github.com/matiasinsaurralde/rust-experiment).

Could this issue occur when multiple threads (on the C side) try to access the callback function pointer concurrently? How would you debug this?

**Update:** I've been debugging this with lldb and came up with this, something is wrong with the function pointer:

```
self.cb = 0x736a73742e
Process 32896 stopped
* thread #1, queue = 'com.apple.main-thread', stop reason = EXC_BAD_ACCESS (code=1, address=0x736a73742e)
    frame #0: 0x000000736a73742e
error: memory read failed for 0x736a737400
```

Comment: *Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and **the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself***. Links to your full code are fine to add, but are not sufficient. Otherwise this question is off topic.

Comment: I agree and have tried to include the shortest snippets possible. I find the use case a bit complex, even the test code I've linked is just a test program that I've built exclusively for this question. Will try to enhance it.

Comment: I believe your question is answered by the answers of [Rust function that allocates memory and calls a C++ callback crashes](https://stackoverflow.com/q/50188710/155423). If you disagree, please [edit] your question to explain the differences. Otherwise, we can mark this question as already answered.

Comment: I've been testing my implementation with `Box::into_raw` but I get the same issue, as I've mentioned in the last paragraphs the callback works fine, it's called `rust_callback`. So: a) `rust_callback` locates the Rust object using a pointer b) This object has a `recv` method and it's called using `(*w).recv(...)`. c) The `recv` method is successfully called, this method calls a function pointer that's part of its data structure, this is the function that fails and the reason why I ask for feedback on the function pointer approach.